# How to set all DIVs to same height to all DIVs in same table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with three columns. Each table cell contain DIVs with different content and one of them contain an image. I have a small JS function that sets the height of the images DIV containers to one of 2 possible heights.

Image natural height is < 60px == container DIV is 60 px high

Image natural height is > 60px = container DIV is 104 px high

Now I need to figure out how to set all three image DIVs to the same height on each table row.

Row with only small images = all three image DIVs should be set to 60px.

Row with one or more large images = all three image DIVs should be set to 104px.

This is my js snippet:

```
    $('div.givarbild img').each( function() {
        var container = $(this).closest('div.givarbild');
        $("<img>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).load(function(){
            var picHeight = this.height;
            console.log(picHeight);
            if(picHeight < 60){
                container.height(60);
            }else{
                container.height(104);
            } 
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="givarbild"">
            <img width="100" height="50" src="image path">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="givarbild"">
            <img width="150" height="50" src="image path">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="givarbild"">
            <img width="90" height="90" src="image path">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My jquery/JS function only sets the current image DIV to 60 or 104 px, so that these container DIVs can have different heights on each row. But as I wrote above, I need to set the same value to all three image containers on each row.
In the HTML example above all DIVs should be 104 px high, since one of the images is over 60px. How can I modify my code snippet to do what I want?

EDITED:
I cannot use 100% height for the DIV with the class `.givarbild` because I also want the images to be vertically centered in the DIVs on each row. The vertical centering is obtained with this css (in order to use `max-height: 100%` the container must be set to a px value:

```
div.givarbild {
    height:100px; /*this value is overridden by my JS*/
    min-width:190px;
    position: relative;
    margin:10px 0px;  
}

.givarbild img {
    max-height: 100%;  
    width:auto; 
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    margin: auto 0; 
}
```

I looked at Flexbox, but it seems a bit over the top for this task? I will investigate further though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Flexbox may be what you are looking for. http://clearleft.com/thinks/270

Comment: Flexbox is the way to go if you do not need to support Internet Explorer 10-. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Going the same way you are already going... in the html you can set the height of each div to be 100%.  Better yet, set the class givarbild to have a height property of 100%.  That will size them to the size of the cell they are contained in.  The cells will autosize to the size of the biggest image, so all of them will be the same height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edited question. I cannot use a percent value for the height unfortunately. That will break the vertical centering of the image in the box.

Comment: Not so, you have to center the image within its container.  If the container takes up 100% of the cell, change its style attribute to display:inline-block, and then set the vertical-align of the image to be "middle".